# Adding validation before closing dialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I need to check if any of the lineEdits is empty before accepting the dialog when clicked on OK button. I tried to override buttonBox accepted slot like this:

```
#self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(Dialog.accept)
self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(Dialog.reject)
QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.validate)

def validate(self, Dialog):
    if (self.lineEdit.text() == '' or self.lineEdit_2.text() == '' or self.lineEdit_3.text() == '' or self.lineEdit_4.text() == '' or self.lineEdit_5.text() == ''):
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.about(QtWidgets.QMessageBox(), 'Error', 'All fields are mandatory!')
    else:
        Dialog.accept()
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: validate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'Dialog'
```

Comment: What is `Dialog`?

Comment: @Sanya It's `QtWidgets.QDialog()` object.

Comment: I am not sure if it will work, but you can try assign `self.dialog = Dialog`, make `validate` a function only with `self` parameter and call `self.dialog.accept()`

Comment: @Sanya This actually worked, thank you! You should make it an actual answer, even though I'm not sure this is the correct way to do this.

Comment: I will do. Can you please tell the type of `buttonBox`?